# How would you populate references nested in an object of an array using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**How would you populate the product fields inside the cart array below?**

```
{
    "_id": "5bbd1c6e2c48f512fcd733b4",
    "cart": [
        {
            "count": 1,
            "_id": "5bbd30ed9417363f345b15fc",
            "product": "5ba93a6d5d907d9512e43b75"
        }
        {
            "count": 2,
            "_id": "5bbd30ed9417363f345babcc",
            "product": "5ba93a6d5d2359512e43b75"
        }
        ],
    "totalItems": 0,
    "name": "kellie"
}
```

**Schema is:**

```
const usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    cart: [
        {
            product: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'product'},
            count: {type: Number},
        },
    ],
    totalItems: {type: Number, default: 0},
    totalPrice: {type: Number},
});
```

I tried to research a solution with no luck.

Comment: What have you tried? Look into mogoose populate and show us an attempt.

Comment: I tried multiple things like Model.find().populate('cart.product').  and Model.find().populate('cart.$.product'). and Model.find().populate({path: 'cart.product', models: 'product'}). and Model.find().populate({path: 'cart.product', populate: {path: 'product', model: 'product'}}); non of them worked.

Comment: Should be `Model.find({})`. Try populate with that and `exec()` as per the `populate` documentation

Comment: Yes I did that. I didn’t add it here but in the app I did put the query in there. The find(query) query works just fine without the populate method. In fact, the populate method also works just fine if the cart array is an array of objectIds only like this:  cart:[{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref: ‘product’}]. But when I changed it to to an array of objects (to add count field) like this: cart: [{product:{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:’product’}, count: Number}]. it didn’t work and I can’t figure out how to make it populate. I’m still currently trying to research the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced you schema (the main part with the `cart.product`) and had no issues populating via the usual `populate.exec()` method:

```
var result = Author.findOne({ _id: "5bbd93a29fceda195bec8665" })
.populate("books.book")
.exec()
.then(result => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

My Author schema had same `card.product` thing but it is `books.book`:

```
var AuthorSchema = new Schema({
  books: [{
      book: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Book" },
      count: {type: Number}
    }
  ]
}
```

Same happens with `Author.find({})` etc.

Comment: I just tried to isolate the code and it worked too on the isolated simple code. however, in my project, it did not work. it seems that the problem is beyond this question because of the way the file is structured. I had the routers  separated from services (logic that interacts with database) and a middle layer between them that instantiate a service and passes the model as a param so that the routers can access its methods. I'm still trying to solve this but if you want to take a look here is the repo populate branch: https://github.com/tito300/Nodejs-Api-Project/tree/populate